# opencl 2.0: Passing struct of arrays to an opencl kernel

Tags: c, struct, kernel, opencl, memory-alignment

The aim is to be able to pass a generic struct between kernels and do basic operations on the array elements within the struct. The array elements are wrapped in a tagged union.

Each array is declared as a one element array, but I am using clSVMAlloc to allocate an array of some predetermined size n. The intention here is to ensure all of the data will reside within the struct, and that the arrays will be located at some offset from the pointer to the struct.

Here are the data structures:

host

```
typedef struct a1 { 
        cl_long r, t, n; 
        union u { cl_long i[1];
                  cl_double f[1];
                  cl_char c[1];
                  cl_char* s[1];
                  struct a1*a[1]; 
                 }u; 
        }AA;
```

device

```
typedef struct a1 { 
        long r, t, n; 
        union u { long i[1];
                  double f[1];
                  char c[1];
                  char* s[1];
                  struct a1*a[1];
                 }u; 
        }AA;
```

The host and device code is compiling. I am using opencl 2.0 with an intel integrated graphics that supports fine grained buffer svm.

The allocation is working.. I can access the struct w.o. issue on the host side. I've attempted to pass the whole struct and also attempted to pass the inner arrays. I am assuming there is some alignment issue going on.

The error that I am seeing is CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS

```
_kernel void plusii(__global long* x,__global long* y,__global long* z,long c){
    int i= gGID(0);
    if(i<c){ 
        z[i]=x[i]+y[i];
    }
}
```

host (assume kaii is a properly initialized kernel that will call plusii, and that gbl=1024 and local=256)

```
#define clENDRK clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
#define clSKASVM clSetKernelArgSVMPointer

clSKASVM(kaii, 0, x->u.i);
clSKASVM(kaii, 1, y->u.i);
clSKASVM(kaii, 2, z->u.i);
clSKASVM(kaii, 3, zn);
e = clENDRK(q, kaii, 1, NULL, &gbl, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: I haven't used SVM so I can't help much, but I do recommend looking at the return value from each call, including the first three to clSetKernelArgSVMPointer, to see which one is returning that error. Also, you are using clSetKernelArgSVMPointer to set a non-SVM parameter. Shouldn't you be using regular clSetKernelArg?

Comment: Than you for your reply! I do use clSVMAlloc for all of my memory management. It returns a pointer to the AA struct. I then pass an element of the u union into the kernel. The u union is a member of the struct, and therefore is some offset from the pointer the clSVMAlloc returned. From perusing thru the docs it looks like this is okay, but I'm not sure if passing the union into he kernel is okay due to alignment issues. I will test and report back.

Comment: I'm not certain if this is true with 2.0 (as I only use 1.2) but I don't believe you can pass pointers to OpenCL kernels within structs; they must be passed as arguments.